# Measure Theory: $X$, $Y$ independent, proof that $P_{X+Y} = P_{X} * P_{Y}$

Tags: measure-theory, convolution, product-measure

I am studying measure theory, and I bumped in the the following: Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with distributions $P_X$ and $P_Y$ respectively. A lot of sources conclude (or use in) the convolution theorem that $P_{X+Y} = P_{X} * P_{Y}$. However, I do not see how this can be proved using measure theory.

The definition concerning convolution I am given from my lecture notes is the following:

$\textit{Let } f,g: \bar{\mathbb{R}} \to [0,\infty) \textit{ be Lebesgue measurable. The convolution product of $f$ and $g$ is defined by}$ $$h(x) = \int_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}} f(x-y)g(y) \; \mathrm{d}m(y), $$
$\forall x \in \bar{\mathbb{R}}\textit{ for which the integrand is Lebesgue integrable.}$ $\textit{The function $h$ is called the convolution of $f$ and $g$, denoted by $h=f*g$}.$

Can anyone explain to me how  $P_{X+Y} = P_{X} * P_{Y}$?

Comment: The definition you are giving is the convolution of two non-negative functions, but your actual question mentions the convolution of two distributions. Do you want that the distribution of the sum is the convolution of the individual distributions or that the density of the sum is the convolution of the individual densities (in case they exist). Both would be valid questions.

Comment: you need to use the definition of the convolution of two measures, for the general case of distributions $F_X$ and $F_Y$

Answer (score 3):

Let $Z:=(X,Y)$, then we have that
$$
\Pr[X+Y\leqslant c]:=\Pr(\{\omega \in \Omega :X(\omega )+Y(\omega )\leqslant c\})\\
=\Pr(\{\omega \in \Omega :x+y\leqslant c\,\land\,(X(\omega ), Y(\omega ))=(x,y)\})\\
=\Pr(\{\omega \in \Omega :x+y\leqslant c\,\land\,Z(\omega)=(x,y)\})\tag1
$$
Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $F_Z=F_X\cdot F_Y$, that is, the distribution of $Z$ is the product of the distributions of $X$ and $Y$; and from $\mathrm{(1)} $ we find that $\Pr[X+Y\leqslant c]=\Pr[Z\in S_c]$ for $S_c:=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R ^2:x+y\leqslant c\}$, so
$$
\Pr[X+Y\leqslant c]=\iint \mathbf{1}_{S_c}(x,y)\,\mathrm d F_X(x) \,\mathrm d F_Y(y)\tag2
$$
Now, the convolution of two measures $\mu $ and $\nu $ is defined by
$$
\mu *\nu (A):=\iint \mathbf{1}_{A}(x+y)\,\mathrm d \mu(x)  \,\mathrm d \nu(y) \tag3
$$
In our case
$$
\,\mathrm d F_X*\,\mathrm d F_Y(A):=\iint \mathbf{1}_{A}(x+y)\,\mathrm d F_X(x) \,\mathrm d F_Y(y)\tag4
$$
Equating both definitions we need to show that
$$
\mathbf{1}_{S_c}(x,y)=\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty ,c]}(x+y)\tag5
$$
what is not hard to see using the definition of $S_c$.